# Values (amplitudes) of the CWT and their relationship to waveform amplitudes?

Tags: wavelet, transform, spectrogram, amplitude

I'm coding up a scalogram in C++. Right now it calculates a single row of the CWT matrix and immediately maps it to a line of pixels.

Trouble is my colouring scales with the values of the transform and naturally brightest colour = highest value. Yet as it is I don't know how to find the maximum value so that I can generate my spectrum. I know CWT is funny with amplitudes so I'm asking for guidance.

Thanks in advance,
a meme